HAProxy: configuring multiple single domain SSL certs for domain and subdomain
I have 2 single domain SSL certs for the following urls:

domain.com
test.domain.com

Due to business requirements, both of those domains will point to the same backend for some period of time (a single instance of a service).
My current relevent HAProxy config info:
frontend my_service_https
    bind: *.8000 ssl crt ./folder_containing_both_pems

backend my_service
    server app1 127.0.0.1:8000 

Issue is, test.domain.com has a SSL mismatch with the current config, and I am not sure how to specify which SSL to use based on the url the client visits.
